# Firebase Firestore batch commits: are the batch's instructions executed in the specified order?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a like/unlike system of posts based on Firestore and Cloud Functions. Currently, I'm setting up a Cloud Function that will be executed when the app user takes a look to the list of posts. This Cloud Function's aim is to count the number of likes of each post, sum up the number of likes of each post of the same post owner, and saves in database the number of likes of all the posts of each post owner into the post owner document.

So:

1. I iterate over all my users documents, and set the number of likes of all their posts to 0. It's an initialization. I use batch updates.
2. Then, I iterate over all the likes. In RAM, for each post owner, I compute the sum of the number of likes of each of the posts he has created. I use JS arrays operations.
3. Then, I iterate over the JS array that contains the post owners' ID associated to the number of the likes of all their posts, and I set the database counter of the number of the likes of all their posts to the value. I use batch updates.

If it's not clear, the code is available below.

My question is: since I first initialize to 0 the counter of all my users documents, and then I affect the good value for the counter of some of them, I actually need to be sure that the 0 init is done before the rest batch updates. Is it the case?

```
exports.sortUsersByUsersPostsLikes = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if(!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
    }

    const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
    const users = admin_firestore.collection('users');
    const likes = admin_firestore.collection('likes_of_users_posts');
    users.get().then(function(users_docs) {
        users_docs.forEach(user_doc => {
            batch.update(user_doc.ref, "number_of_likes_of_users_posts", 0);
        });

        return likes.get();

    }).then(function(likes_docs) {
        const map_users_id_with_number_of_likes = [];
        likes_docs.forEach(like_doc => {
            if(!(like_doc.data().post_owner in map_users_id_with_number_of_likes)) {
                map_users_id_with_number_of_likes[like_doc.data().post_owner] = 0;
            }
            map_users_id_with_number_of_likes[like_doc.data().post_owner] += 1;
        });
        Object.keys(map_users_id_with_number_of_likes).forEach((k) => {
            const user = admin_firestore.collection('users').doc(k);
            batch.update(user, "number_of_likes_of_users_posts", map_users_id_with_number_of_likes[k]);
        }); 
        return batch.commit();

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("UNABLE TO SORT THE USERS");
        console.log(error);
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'An error occurred when trying to sort the users.');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Batches and transactions complete all at once, atomically, or not at all.  There is no order.  If you set the value of a field twice, only the last value you specify as you build the batch will take effect.

If you're asking about Cloud Functions triggers that might happen in response to a document update, there is never an ordering guarantee for those trigger.

Comment: Doug, in fact I'm putting into my batch updates "field to 0" for all the documents of a collection, then I'm putting into this same batch "field to 1" for some documents of this same collection. My idea was to initialize to 0 the field of all docs, then bring the correct value to the field of arbitrary chosen docs. So I really need to be sure that the first batch updates, which are init to 0, are executed before the others. - Edit : do you think I must make my question more precise?

Comment: Yes, your question should have been precise about what you're trying to do.  Only the last update will matter for a particular field, since a batch is held in memory until committed, and it normally doesn't make sense to update a field twice when you know the final value.